# No video feed with DUXDefaultLayoutViewController for Mavic Mini

Tags: swift, dji-sdk

In my toy project, I'm using code from sample [UXSDKSwiftSample](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/tree/master/Sample%20Code/SwiftSampleCode/UXSDKSwiftSample) written in Swift. Basically it's just empty storyboard and controller extending DUXDefaultLayoutViewController and ProductCommunicationService found in the example .

The app connects to Mavic Mini and display basic information, like battery status and also can take photos, but no video feed. I just see label "Mavic Mini Camera".

Strangely I can get video feed using DJIWidget example, but not with this UXSDKSwiftSample example mentioned above.

Any ideas what do I do wrong?

I'm not using cocoapods, but downloaded all SDKs from dji download page:

- iOS_UX_SDK_4.13.zip
- iOS_Mobile_SDK_4.13.1.zip
- DJIWidget from github master branch

I'm testing on iPhone 11 Pro and iOS 14.1